# ¿Por qué esta app de Vue no me coje la altura completa de la pantalla?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

No tengo en ningún sitio indicado que el height esté al 50% o similares, pero abiendo las devtools el height del html sólo es 661px y yo no lo he indicado en ningun sitio. ¿Como hacer que ocupe el 100% height de la pantalla?

App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  background: #51BA8A;
}
</style>
```

TodoList.vue

```js
<template>

  <div id="TodoList" class="presentation-container">
    <h1 v-if="message_2 === ''">{{ message }}</h1>
    <h1 v-if="message_2 !== ''">{{ message_2 + "´s to-do list" }}</h1>
    <div>
      <input id="input-name" v-model="message_2" />
      <button id="newT-tbn" v-on:click="openTodo()">New To-Do List</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Todo cards: -->
    <div classname="card-containers">
      <div classname="card">
        <input />
        <button>Add Task</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: 'TodoList',
  data () {
    return {
      message: "Name Your To-Do",
      message_2: "",
    }
  },
  methods(){
    
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap');
body{
  color: #F8F8F8;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
.presentation-container{
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 2px solid #F8F8F8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
  width: 35vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /* Change height onclick: */
}
.pre-container-clicked{
    height: 400px;
}
.input-name-ocult{
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Seteaste html, body { height: 100% } en algún lado?. Por defecto son elementos block, por lo cual ocupan la altura de su contenido (más padding dependiendo del box-size).

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que indique html, body { height: 100% } en <style> de App.vue?